NSPanGesture not working on AppKit but UIPanGesture works on iOS (Multiplatform App)
I found an old SwiftUI library that I've attempted to port to MacOS. You can find the full repo here: https://github.com/cyrilzakka/SlidingRuler. Essentially it's a sliding ruler with ticker stickiness implemented. A screenshot is available below:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
As is, the code works perfectly on iOS and I'm able to drag the slider left and right to modify values. On macOS (AppKit) while the UI looks good, the dragging of the slider doesn't seem to work.
Here's HorizontalPanGesture.swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreGeometry

#if canImport(UIKit)
struct HorizontalDragGestureValue {
    let state: UIGestureRecognizer.State
    let translation: CGSize
    let velocity: CGFloat
    let startLocation: CGPoint
    let location: CGPoint
}

protocol HorizontalPanGestureReceiverViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func viewTouchedWithoutPan(_ view: UIView)
}

class HorizontalPanGestureReceiverView: UIView {
    weak var delegate: HorizontalPanGestureReceiverViewDelegate?

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        delegate?.viewTouchedWithoutPan(self)
    }
}

extension View {
    func onHorizontalDragGesture(initialTouch: @escaping () -> () = { },
                                 prematureEnd: @escaping () -> () = { },
                                 perform action: @escaping (HorizontalDragGestureValue) -> ()) -> some View {
        self.overlay(HorizontalPanGesture(beginTouch: initialTouch, prematureEnd: prematureEnd, action: action))
    }
}

private struct HorizontalPanGesture: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias Action = (HorizontalDragGestureValue) -> ()
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, HorizontalPanGestureReceiverViewDelegate {
        private let beginTouch: () -> ()
        private let prematureEnd: () -> ()
        private let action: Action
        weak var view: UIView?
        
        init(_ beginTouch: @escaping () -> () = { }, _ prematureEnd: @escaping () -> () = { }, _ action: @escaping Action) {
            self.beginTouch = beginTouch
            self.prematureEnd = prematureEnd
            self.action = action
        }
        
        @objc func panGestureHandler(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
            let velocity = gesture.velocity(in: view)
            let location = gesture.location(in: view)
            let startLocation = location - translation

            let value = HorizontalDragGestureValue(state: gesture.state,
                                                   translation: .init(horizontal: translation.x),
                                                   velocity: velocity.x,
                                                   startLocation: startLocation,
                                                   location: location)
            self.action(value)
        }
        
        func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            guard let pgr = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer else { return false }
            let velocity = pgr.velocity(in: view)
            return abs(velocity.x) > abs(velocity.y)
        }

        func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive event: UIEvent) -> Bool {
            beginTouch()
            return true
        }

        func viewTouchedWithoutPan(_ view: UIView) {
            prematureEnd()
        }
    }

    @Environment(\.slidingRulerStyle) private var style
    
    let beginTouch: () -> ()
    let prematureEnd: () -> ()
    let action: Action
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        .init(beginTouch, prematureEnd, action)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = HorizontalPanGestureReceiverView(frame: .init(size: .init(square: 42)))
        let pgr = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.panGestureHandler(_:)))
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        pgr.delegate = context.coordinator
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pgr)
        context.coordinator.view = view

        // Pointer interactions
        if #available(iOS 13.4, *), style.supportsPointerInteraction {
            pgr.allowedScrollTypesMask = .continuous
            view.addInteraction(UIPointerInteraction(delegate: context.coordinator))
        }

        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) { }
}

@available(iOS 13.4, *)
extension HorizontalPanGesture.Coordinator: UIPointerInteractionDelegate {
    func pointerInteraction(_ interaction: UIPointerInteraction, styleFor region: UIPointerRegion) -> UIPointerStyle? {
        .init(shape: .path(Pointers.standard), constrainedAxes: .vertical)
    }
}


#elseif canImport(AppKit)
struct HorizontalDragGestureValue {
    let state: NSGestureRecognizer.State
    let translation: CGSize
    let velocity: CGFloat
    let startLocation: CGPoint
    let location: CGPoint
}

protocol HorizontalPanGestureReceiverViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func viewTouchedWithoutPan(_ view: NSView)
}

class HorizontalPanGestureReceiverView: NSView {
    weak var delegate: HorizontalPanGestureReceiverViewDelegate?
    
    override func touchesEnded(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.touchesEnded(with: event)
        delegate?.viewTouchedWithoutPan(self)
    }
}

extension View {
    func onHorizontalDragGesture(initialTouch: @escaping () -> () = { },
                                 prematureEnd: @escaping () -> () = { },
                                 perform action: @escaping (HorizontalDragGestureValue) -> ()) -> some View {
        self.overlay(HorizontalPanGesture(beginTouch: initialTouch, prematureEnd: prematureEnd, action: action))
    }
}

private struct HorizontalPanGesture: NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias Action = (HorizontalDragGestureValue) -> ()

    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSGestureRecognizerDelegate, HorizontalPanGestureReceiverViewDelegate {
        private let beginTouch: () -> ()
        private let prematureEnd: () -> ()
        private let action: Action
        weak var view: NSView?
        
        init(_ beginTouch: @escaping () -> () = { }, _ prematureEnd: @escaping () -> () = { }, _ action: @escaping Action) {
            self.beginTouch = beginTouch
            self.prematureEnd = prematureEnd
            self.action = action
        }
        
        @objc func panGestureHandler(_ gesture: NSPanGestureRecognizer) {
            print("PanGesture handler called")
            let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
            let velocity = gesture.velocity(in: view)
            let location = gesture.location(in: view)
            let startLocation = location - translation

            let value = HorizontalDragGestureValue(state: gesture.state,
                                                   translation: .init(horizontal: translation.x),
                                                   velocity: velocity.x,
                                                   startLocation: startLocation,
                                                   location: location)
            self.action(value)
        }
        
        func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: NSGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            guard let pgr = gestureRecognizer as? NSPanGestureRecognizer else { return false }
            let velocity = pgr.velocity(in: view)
            return abs(velocity.x) > abs(velocity.y)
        }
        
        func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: NSGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: NSTouch) -> Bool {
            beginTouch()
            return true
        }

        func viewTouchedWithoutPan(_ view: NSView) {
            prematureEnd()
        }
    }
    
    @Environment(\.slidingRulerStyle) private var style
    
    let beginTouch: () -> ()
    let prematureEnd: () -> ()
    let action: Action
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        .init(beginTouch, prematureEnd, action)
    }
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> some NSView {
        let view = HorizontalPanGestureReceiverView(frame: .init(size: .init(square: 42)))
        let pgr = NSPanGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.panGestureHandler(_:)))
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        pgr.delegate = context.coordinator
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pgr)
        context.coordinator.view = view

        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSViewType, context: Context) { }
}

#endif

and how it's used:
public var body: some View {
        let renderedValue: CGFloat, renderedOffset: CGSize

        (renderedValue, renderedOffset) = renderingValues()

        return FlexibleWidthContainer {
            ZStack(alignment: .init(horizontal: .center, vertical: self.verticalCursorAlignment)) {
                Ruler(cells: self.cells, step: self.step, markOffset: self.markOffset, bounds: self.bounds, formatter: self.formatter)
                    .equatable()
                    .animation(nil)
                    .modifier(InfiniteOffsetEffect(offset: renderedOffset, maxOffset: self.cellWidthOverflow))
                self.style.makeCursorBody()
            }
        }

        .modifier(InfiniteMarkOffsetModifier(renderedValue, step: step))
        .propagateWidth(ControlWidthPreferenceKey.self)
        .onPreferenceChange(MarkOffsetPreferenceKey.self, storeValueIn: $markOffset)
        .onPreferenceChange(ControlWidthPreferenceKey.self, storeValueIn: $controlWidth) {
            self.updateCellsIfNeeded()
        }
        .transaction {
            if $0.animation != nil { $0.animation = .easeIn(duration: 0.1) }
        }
        .onHorizontalDragGesture(initialTouch: firstTouchHappened,
                                 prematureEnd: panGestureEndedPrematurely,
                                 perform: horizontalDragAction(withValue:))
    }

I can't seem to find where I could be going wrong.
The only other potential (but less likely) problematic part could be CADisplayLink which I had to implement differently on macOS:
#if canImport(UIKit)
import UIKit
#elseif canImport(AppKit)
import AppKit
import CoreVideo
#endif

struct VSynchedTimer {
    typealias Animations = (TimeInterval, TimeInterval) -> ()
    typealias Completion = (Bool) -> ()
    
    private let timer: SynchedTimer
    
    init(duration: TimeInterval, animations: @escaping Animations, completion: Completion? = nil) {
        self.timer = .init(duration, animations, completion)
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        timer.cancel()
    }
}


private final class SynchedTimer {
    private let duration: TimeInterval
    private let animationBlock: VSynchedTimer.Animations
    private let completionBlock: VSynchedTimer.Completion?
#if canImport(UIKit)
    private weak var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
#elseif canImport(AppKit)
    private var displayLink: CVDisplayLink?
#endif
    
    private var isRunning: Bool
    private let startTimeStamp: TimeInterval
    private var lastTimeStamp: TimeInterval
    
    deinit {
        cancel()
    }
    
    init(_ duration: TimeInterval, _ animations: @escaping VSynchedTimer.Animations, _ completion: VSynchedTimer.Completion? = nil) {
        self.duration = duration
        self.animationBlock = animations
        self.completionBlock = completion
        
        self.isRunning = true
        self.startTimeStamp = CACurrentMediaTime()
        self.lastTimeStamp = startTimeStamp
        self.displayLink = self.createDisplayLink()
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        guard isRunning else { return }
        
        isRunning.toggle()
#if canImport(UIKit)
        displayLink?.invalidate()
#elseif canImport(AppKit)
        CVDisplayLinkStop(displayLink!)
#endif
        self.completionBlock?(false)
    }
    
    private func complete() {
        guard isRunning else { return }
        
        isRunning.toggle()
#if canImport(UIKit)
        displayLink?.invalidate()
#elseif canImport(AppKit)
        CVDisplayLinkStop(displayLink!)
#endif
        self.completionBlock?(true)
    }
    
    @objc private func displayLinkTick(_ displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
        guard isRunning else { return }
        
        let currentTimeStamp = CACurrentMediaTime()
        let progress = currentTimeStamp - startTimeStamp
        let elapsed = currentTimeStamp - lastTimeStamp
        lastTimeStamp = currentTimeStamp
        
        if progress < duration {
            animationBlock(progress, elapsed)
        } else {
            complete()
        }
    }
    
#if canImport(UIKit)
    private func createDisplayLink() -> CADisplayLink {
        let dl = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(displayLinkTick(_:)))
        dl.add(to: .main, forMode: .common)
        
        return dl
    }
#elseif canImport(AppKit)
    private func createDisplayLink() -> CVDisplayLink? {
        var cvDisplayLink: CVDisplayLink?
        CVDisplayLinkCreateWithActiveCGDisplays(&cvDisplayLink)
        guard let displayLink = cvDisplayLink else { return nil }
        
        CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(displayLink, { (displayLink, inNow, inOutputTime, flagsIn, flagsOut, userInfo) -> CVReturn in
            guard let context = userInfo else { return kCVReturnError }
            let synchedTimer = Unmanaged<SynchedTimer>.fromOpaque(context).takeUnretainedValue()
            synchedTimer.displayLinkTick()
            return kCVReturnSuccess
        }, Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
        
        CVDisplayLinkStart(displayLink)
        return displayLink
    }
    
    @objc private func displayLinkTick() {
        guard isRunning else { return }
        
        let currentTimeStamp = CACurrentMediaTime()
        let progress = currentTimeStamp - startTimeStamp
        let elapsed = currentTimeStamp - lastTimeStamp
        lastTimeStamp = currentTimeStamp
        
        if progress < duration {
            animationBlock(progress, elapsed)
        } else {
            complete()
        }
    }
#endif
    
}

Any help debugging this would be greatly appreciated. Adding other native SwiftUI gestures to the view work (onTap, drag etc), but I want to keep things similar between both platforms.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Ch38BDrk.png

After debugging overnight, it seems
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: NSGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            guard let pgr = gestureRecognizer as? NSPanGestureRecognizer else { return false }
            let velocity = pgr.velocity(in: view)
            print(abs(velocity.x) > abs(velocity.y), abs(velocity.x), abs(velocity.y))
            return abs(velocity.x) > abs(velocity.y)
        }

always returns false and because velocity is always 0.  So more debugging there but at least my primary issue is solved.
